# Transfer large of data using wcf service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, maxstringcontentlength

When I try to transfer a large data in WCF, I get this error:

> *The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:requete. The InnerException message was 'There was
>   an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The maximum
>   string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML
>   data. This quota may be increased by changing the
>   MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
>   object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 8843.'.
>   Please see InnerException for more details.*

This is my `app.config` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" maxBufferSize="52428800" maxBufferPoolSize="52428800">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="52428800" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="TSO_WCF.Service1">
        <host>
           <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TSO_WCF/Service1/" />
           </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TSO_WCF.IService1" >
           <identity>
              <dns value="localhost"/>
           </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
          </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<appSettings>
   <add key="Mapping" value="D:\workspace\oddo.app.ldw.tsomanagertool\ProjetTSO\MappingsXML"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should increse the MaxStringContentLength on the server and client binding. At this moment you are using the default value of 8192.

Comment: I've increased it by I still have the same error, I think that I should change my binding but I don't know how

Comment: @user1805523: and you will have to do this configuration change on **both** - the server **and** the client .

Comment: have you an idea about how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change your binding /use streaming. See this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

Comment: Do you have a documentation easier because I'm a beginner